# Choosing more profitable stream result

Tags: java, java-8, stream, java-stream

currently I am struggling with a discount calculation problem in my small product management application.

```
public class Customer {
  private String name;
  private String surname;
  private LocalDate birthDate;
  private String email;
}

public class Order {
  private Customer customer;
  private Product product;
  private Integer quantity;
  private LocalDate estimatedRealizationDate;
}

public class Product {
  private String name;
  private BigDecimal price;
  private Category category;
}
```

With lombok utilities.

I have an Orders class which contains an order list.

```
public class Orders {

    private final List<Order> productList;

    private static final int MAXIMAL_AGE_WITH_DISCOUNT = 25;
    private static final BigDecimal DISCOUNT_RATIO_FOR_CUSTOMER_YOUNGER_THAN_25 = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.97);
    private static final BigDecimal DISCOUNT_RATIO_FOR_ESTIMATED_DELIVERY_DATE_SMALLER_THAN_2 = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.98);
    private static final int MAXIMAL_DATES_NUMBER_FOR_DISCOUNT = 2;
}
```

Below one order example:

```
Orders orderList =
        new Orders(
            newArrayList(
                Order.builder()
                    .product(new Product("LEVER", BigDecimal.valueOf(120), Category.C))
                    .customer(new Customer("JACK", "MULLER", LocalDate.of(1980, 7, 3), "jackmuller@gmail.com"))
                    .estimatedRealizationDate(LocalDate.now().plusDays(2))
                    .quantity(5)
                    .build());
```

I would like to give a 3% discount for every customer under 25 years of age and a 2% discount for an order which estimated delivery date is smaller than 2 days from this moment but I want to choose a more profitable discount for the customer.

I wrote my snippet code but as far as I see my version will combine discounts in some cases and this is not desirable.

```
BigDecimal totalPriceOfAllOrdersAfterPriceReduction() {
        return productList.stream().map(i -> {
            if (between(i.getCustomer().getBirthDate(), LocalDate.now()).getYears() < MAXIMAL_AGE_WITH_DISCOUNT) {
                return i.getProduct().getPrice().multiply(DISCOUNT_RATIO_FOR_CUSTOMER_YOUNGER_THAN_25).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(i.getQuantity()));
            }
            if (between(i.getEstimatedRealizationDate(), LocalDate.now()).getDays() < MAXIMAL_DATES_NUMBER_FOR_DISCOUNT) {
                return i.getProduct().getPrice().multiply(DISCOUNT_RATIO_FOR_ESTIMATED_DELIVERY_DATE_SMALLER_THAN_2).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(i.getQuantity()));
            }
            return i.getProduct().getPrice();
        }).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
    }
```

After the entire operation, I want to sum up the total prices of all orders (quantity * price).

I want to make it happened with Java stream usage.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Side-question: why are you using `BigDecimal`? Shouldn't an `int` of the smallest currency suffice? Something like `int priceInCents = 100;` where `100` cents equal `1` dollar?

Comment: It is common and considered safe to use the BigDecimal class when working with currencies, so I use it in this case. By the way, your solution is pretty considerable, I will certainly go deeper into it after the problem has been solved.

Comment: It's the loss of precision I guess that makes the `int` "unsafe", you could of course do your computation with `double` values, but then return `int` again. That way you keep the precision throughout the calculation but then work again with `int`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put the second if in the else part of the first one

```
BigDecimal totalPriceOfAllOrdersAfterPriceReduction() {
        return productList.stream().map(i -> {
            if (between(i.getCustomer().getBirthDate(), LocalDate.now()).getYears() < MAXIMAL_AGE_WITH_DISCOUNT) {
                return i.getProduct().getPrice().multiply(DISCOUNT_RATIO_FOR_CUSTOMER_YOUNGER_THAN_25).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(i.getQuantity()));
            } else{
               if (between(i.getEstimatedRealizationDate(), LocalDate.now()).getDays() < MAXIMAL_DATES_NUMBER_FOR_DISCOUNT) {
                   return i.getProduct().getPrice().multiply(DISCOUNT_RATIO_FOR_ESTIMATED_DELIVERY_DATE_SMALLER_THAN_2).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(i.getQuantity()));
               }
            }
            return i.getProduct().getPrice();
        }).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
    }
```

Another track to make it more readable and trackable, is to add a "discount" field on the order and then

```
 @Builder
    @Getter
    @ToString
    public static class Order {
        private Customer customer;
        private Product product;
        private Integer quantity;
        private LocalDate estimatedRealizationDate;
        private BigDecimal discount = BigDecimal.ZERO;

        public boolean threePercent(){
            return Period.between(this.getCustomer().birthDate, LocalDate.now()).getYears() < MAXIMAL_AGE_WITH_DISCOUNT;
        }

        public boolean twoPercent(){
            return Period.between(this.estimatedRealizationDate, LocalDate.now()).getYears() < MAXIMAL_DATES_NUMBER_FOR_DISCOUNT;
        }


    }

    public static Order update(Order o){
        if(o.threePercent()){
            o.discount = DISCOUNT_RATIO_FOR_CUSTOMER_YOUNGER_THAN_25;
        }else{
            if(o.twoPercent()){
                o.discount = DISCOUNT_RATIO_FOR_ESTIMATED_DELIVERY_DATE_SMALLER_THAN_2;
            }
        }
        return o;
    }

    public static BigDecimal totalPriceOfAllOrdersAfterPriceReduction(List<Order> orders){
        return orders
                .stream()
                .map(Scratch::update)
                .peek(System.out::println)
                .map(o -> o.product.price.multiply(o.discount).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(o.quantity)))
                .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
    }
```